# Adding a namespace to the top of my PHP functions page results in the display of an entirely blank page (with no errors)

Tags: php, namespaces

I am using **PHP Version 7.3.25**.

I have started experimenting with **PHP Namespaces** on the server-side (not least because I use **ESModules** on the client-side and I fully appreciate the advantages of namespacing) but I have fallen at the first hurdle - it's probably an obvious rookie error, but with no errors displaying it's difficult to guess what mistake I've made.

I have a long page of global functions - included before anything else by every page on the website - which I have prepended with:

```
namespace mySetup\myFunctions;
```

On every page on the site, I include this long page of global functions, using:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my-setup/my-functions.php';

getMyPage();
```

I can't guess what is going wrong now because the result (for every page) is now an entirely blank page with no error.

Although the long page only contains functions (no classes), I wondered if I might need to change the function invocation `getMyPage();` to:

```
\mySetup\myFunctions\getMyPage();
```

But that also doesn't work. So I'm a little lost, unable to even guess at what basic, low-level consideration is going wrong or which I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you either have to prefix the function with its namespace (use the fully qualified name of it) or alias the function before calling it using the `use` statement (usually right after the namespace declaration - if any - or at the beginning of the file otherwise).

```php
<?php

use mySetup\myFunctions\getMyPage;

...

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my-setup/my-functions.php';

getMyPage();
```

Note that the `use ...` statement does not import the function per se. It only creates a short alias for it, so you won't have to use the FQN.
The [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) is pretty useful for learning the basics, but only you have to keep in mind this slight misuse of "importing" keyword.

EDIT: Namespaces can be used for autoloading (auto-importing) of classes (functions not supported), take a look at [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for the basics, then consider using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

EDIT 2: Also the blank page means a fatal error with error reporting / displaying turned off. Check the PHP log, the error will be there.